# Registering and unregistering BroadcastReceiver in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

My app has an action bar with 3 fragment tabs.
In the second fragment I register and unregister a BroadcastReceiver.
I unregister the receiver in `onPause` and register it in `onCreateView` and in `onResume`.

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

and

```
getActivity().unregisterReceiver(batteryInfoReceiver);
```

**1) Is it all right to register the same reciever twice (in onCreateView and onResume)?(is it harmless?)**

**2) Is it enough to just register the reciever in onResume?**

Comment: I got an unregister error when I was trying it on a fragment. The problem I faced was that - I was trying to unregister twice. Once on onDestroy() and once on onPause(). I also did register once on onCreate() and once on onResume(). Later on looking at the life-cycle of the fragment, I found out I just need to register on onResume() and unregister on onPause(). This is enough to register and unregister on a fragment.

Hope this helps someone doing broadcast with fragments. :)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Have a look at [life-cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) of `Fragments`:

**onCreateView():**
The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not provide a UI.

**onResume():** 
The fragment is visible in the running activity

**onPause():**
This is usually where you should commit any changes that should be persisted beyond the current user session (because the user might not come back).

**Conclusion:**

So it is better to  **register the receiver only inside `onResume()` and unregister inside `onPause()`** because `onCreateView()` deals with view hierarchy only. It has nothing to do with receiver. So it is not harmful but surely it is useless.

I hope it will be helpful!!

Answer (score 17):

Here is code that works for me:

Inside layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="sendInternalBroadcast"
    android:text="Broadcast"/>
```

Fragment Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment One"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentoneTextView1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

inside Main Activity:

```
    public void sendInternalBroadcast(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.codingbadly.stefanronnkvist.simplebroadcastreceiver.setup");
    intent.putExtra("From", "sendInternalBroadcast");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Fragment:

```
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment
{
    View view;
    Context _context;
    PendingIntent pi;
    BroadcastReceiver br;
    AlarmManager am;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentone, container, false);
        setup();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
        _context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView()
    {
        super.onDestroyView();
        _context.unregisterReceiver(br);
    }


    private void setup()
    {
        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i)
            {
                TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentoneTextView1);
                tv.setText("onReceive");
            }
        };
        _context.registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.codingbadly.stefanronnkvist.simplebroadcastreceiver.setup"));
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(_context, 0, new Intent("com.codingbadly.stefanronnkvist.simplebroadcastreceiver.setup"), 0);
        am = (AlarmManager)(_context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
    }
}
```

Good Luck..
Stefan Ronnkvist

Comment: Your solution is great! And please correct your profile, man. user1579736 is not cool But you are!

Comment: I think the only question here is `when` to register the receiver. Make your answer great and clear, don't dump all your code, especially the UI files.

Answer (score 5):

**OnResume Register:**

```
context.registerReceiver(receiver,IntentFilter(BroadCastAction.action_success))
```

**onPause unRegister :**

```
context.unregisterReceiver(mContactBroadCastReceiver);
```

Answer (score 2):

With Fragment, you will end up getting the exception `Receiver not registered` in some cases as in my case.

To resolve this, I used

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).registerReceiver(myReceiver,IntentFilter(...))
```

instead of

```
 activity.registerReceiver(paxAmountReceiver,IntentFilter(...))
```

Similarly to unregister, use in `onDestroyView()` (For Eg.)

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).unregister(myReceiver)
```

Comment: Isn't LocalBroadcastManager used only for when you use the Intents within your own app, and not between apps?