# Where in a Fragment should I unregister a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I have a Fragment with a ListView and a BroadcastReceiver that updates the ListView when new data arrives. The Fragments life is controlled by a ViewPager.

In regard to where to (un)register the BroadcastReceiver, I found [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16617831/476074) [places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10780412/476074) suggesting to do it in

`onResume()`:

```
refreshReceiver = new RefreshReceiver();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
        refreshReceiver,
        refreshIntentFilter);
```

`onPause()`:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(refreshReceiver);
```

However, this does not work properly. When I long-press the home button to get to the *Recent apps* screen, `onPause()` is called. When new information comes in while I'm on *Recent apps*, the ListView misses the update and shows old information after I go back there.

Now I was thinking about moving the unregistering to the `onStop()` method (or even in [`onDestroy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805733/476074)), but is that guaranteed to be called when the fragment is destroyed? I was worried because if the BroadcastManager holds a reference to the BroadcastReceiver and that in turn holds a reference to the Fragment, it would be quite a serious memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need receiver, then unregister it. if you use it only in that fragment, you may consider unregistering it onViewDestroyed().

Answer (score 0):

According [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616654/registering-and-unregistering-broadcastreceiver-in-a-fragment#answer-16617831) , if your fragment is single and not in pager you can un/register LBM in :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
            broadcast_manager, new IntentFilter("filter"));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(broadcast_manager);
}
```

Else you need to find out when `fragment` is visible then register LBM.

through this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
      super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
      if (visible) {
          // Register LBM
      }
   }
 // ...
}
```

you can register LBM in fragment