# Send data from Service to Fragment, Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, service, android-service

Good evening! 
 I have small problem with Service. At first, I have fragment with several TextViews. Into these TextView I want put text from my Service. And this code of my simple Service

```
public class ChallengeService extends Service {
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    private String url = "";
    public static ArrayList<Exercises> exercises = new ArrayList<>();

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
        url = intent.getStringExtra("Challenge_URL");
        new getChallenge(url).execute();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBind");
        return null;
    }

    public class getChallenge extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        String mUrl;
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String result = "";

        public getChallenge(String url) {
            this.mUrl = url;
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.d("Background", "inBackground");
            try {
                URL mUrl = new URL(url);
                Log.d("URL!!!!", "url = " + url);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                result = buffer.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, strJson + " " + url);
            exercises = ParseJSON.ChallengeParseJSON(strJson);
            Log.d("Challenges", "challenges: " + exercises.get(0).getName() + " " + exercises.get(1).getName());
        }
    }
}
```

And I need send list of ***exercises*** to my Fragment, how can I make it?
I'm new with Services, and I haven't any idea, please help me

Answer (score 4):

Simply broadcast the result from your service and receive it in your fragment through a Broadcast Receiver

You could, for example, broadcast your exercises in the `onPostExecute` like this

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, strJson + " " + url);
        exercises = ParseJSON.ChallengeParseJSON(strJson);
        Log.d("Challenges", "challenges: " + exercises.get(0).getName() + " " + exercises.get(1).getName());

        Intent intent = new Intent(FILTER); //FILTER is a string to identify this intent
        intent.putExtra(MY_KEY, exercises); 
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

However, Your Exercise object needs to be [parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for this to work smoothly. Or you could just broadcast your raw json string and call your `ParseJSON.ChallengeParseJSON(strJson);` in your fragment

Then in your Fragment you create a receiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  ArrayList<Exercises> exercises = intent.getExtras().get(MY_KEY);

  //or
  //exercises = ParseJSON.ChallengeParseJSON(intent.getStringExtra(MY_KEY));

   }
};
```

and [register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616654/register-and-unregister-broadcast-receiver-in-a-fragment) it in your `onResume`

```
  @Override
 protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(FILTER));
 }
```

You also need to unregister it in your onPause using `getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);`

You can also read more about it [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#tutorial_intentservice) if interested

Comment: Any idea on how to do this continuously? In my application I need data to be received every time there is a change in the value.

Comment: Is this the best way to send data from service to fragment? is there any other way? Can you provide documentation to assert your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by 2 methods.

1. Save data to database and get data in fragment.
2. Use Broadcast