# How to add non pending intent action to chrome custom tabs toolbar menu?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

We know that we can add some action buttons to chrome custom tabs. For this we have to create `pending intent` and then it will be able to be added. Right now I have such action button at toolbar:

```
val icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share)
        val intent = Intent(context, MessageWrite::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("mail_type", 6)
        intent.putExtra("theme", "Заявка для Вашей работы $jobTitle")
        intent.putExtra("body", "")
        intent.putExtra("kind", 6)
        if (companyMail.isNotEmpty()) {
            intent.putExtra("receiver_mail", companyMail)
        }
        intent.putExtra("job_lst_type", 4)
        val pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        builder.setActionButton(icon, "Write to company", pi)
```

but I would like to make two things:

1. Add item to menu, not to toolbar like icon.
2. Call function when I press on this icon, not moving to another `activity`.
   So, how I can do it because as I see I have to use pending intents for making it, but I don't know how to do it with `pending intent`.

Comment: you will have  to stick with pending intents because chrome custom tabs are opening the Chrome app in fact, where you can't modify anything. Also with the `PendingIntent` you can not only start the activity, but a service, or broadcast receiver also, so you may want to use broadcastreceiver, and call the required function in it.

Comment: but how I can use this receiver at fragment from which I have opened tabs?

Comment: register the receiver in that fragment probably?

Comment: this fragment is placed in container, so, I will have to add receiver to fragment or to activity?and then how to work with it?

Comment: you can add it to any of them. If you add it to activity, then you have to call your required method of fragment instance in BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive()` method. If you register it in fragment - you can call the method directly by name

Comment: ok, thank you for your help, if I have some question else, could I write you here?

Comment: sure, if you continue in this comments - make sure you mention me with `@`, like @VladyslavMatviienko so I see the notification. Also if you will have some code to show, please edit the question, don;t put the code in comments

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, I don't understand how to make what I want. As I got I have to register receiver at fragment but I can't find any tutorial :(

Comment: searching for `android register receiver in fragment` will give you the answer.

Comment: I found this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275423/how-to-send-a-data-from-a-broadcast-receiver-to-fragment, but as I see I have to add intent filter but I won't need it inside my fragment

Comment: You need to use intent filter, as that is the only way to show which broadcasts your receiver wants to receive. It does not relate to fragment.