# Broadcast receiver is not being registered in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth

I have one button in fragment. When i click on that button - register broadcast and display available bluetooth devices in log. 
When i am working with below code, receiver is not being registered. 
Thanks in advance.

Below is my code.

Method to call when button clicked:

```
private void buttonGetsClicked() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(bleDiscovery, filter);
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
    {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
}
```

Broadcast receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver bleDiscovery = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("receivecalled","receiver called");
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    // Discovery has found a device. Get the 
                    // object and its info from the Intent.
                    BluetoothDevice device = 
intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    String deviceName = device.getName();
                    String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // 
MAC address

                    Log.d("device Name","device Name"+deviceName);
                    Log.d("device id","device Id"+deviceHardwareAddress);
                }
    }
};
```

Comment: Show your `Manifest` file, not sure if you have defined permission in the manifest

Comment: Try to register the broadcast in onResume method and unregister in onPause method in Fragment rather than register on button click. Here is the reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/16617831/1556997

Comment: @TaseerAhmad - These are <permissions> that i have defined in manifest file. '    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" 
    />
     <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> '

Comment: @MiteshSardhara - Even i did that. registered in onResume() and unregistered in onPasue(). But doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Can you try putting pause between cancelDiscovery() and startDiscovery() method and make sure that peer device is in discoverable mode.